# Rails/NGinx - Cant get gzip compression of page working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I got a Rails app (3.2.x) running on Ubuntu and using Passenger.

I added the option

```
gzip on;
```

into the nginx.conf file but testing the page with

```
http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php
```

shows that compression is not used.

My nginx.conf file looks as follows:

```
worker_processes  8;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    server {
      listen    80;
      server_name  xxx.com;
      root /var/www/xxx/public;  
      rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
      passenger_enabled on;
    }
    server {
      listen 443;
      server_name xxx.com;
      root /var/www/xxx/public;
      passenger_enabled on;
      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/private/ssl_xxx_com_certificate.txt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl_xxx_com_private_key.txt;
      ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/private/cabundle.txt;
      ssl_session_timeout  5m;
      ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
      ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You gzip is working. Maybe you shouldn't use web browser to verify that. I used curl and it shows that gzip is on. See the last line.

```
 curl -IL -H "accept-encoding: gzip" http://vircurex.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.2.6
Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2013 10:52:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://vircurex.com/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.19
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "b36d8bb7e713ad93aeb6e5fb1e351135"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: v0100session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTEyZjQ0ZGJjOWI0NTQ4ZGMwNGQxZWM2YTNiZWJjZDcxBjsAVEkiFmlucHV0X2RldmljZV90eXBlBjsARkkiCk1PVVNFBjsARkkiFGhvdmVyX3N1cHBvcnRlZAY7AEZUSSIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4GOwBGSSIxRmNkOGViQXlTL0t1K3l2TTlVVUQwbmFZVW1VZHpoQ1kwT2JkZlhrU3pDZz0GOwBG--3cc39d4d71943811224fb350b8ed6cd0a7d6e363; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: c1be4f7e0ebaffbdfd7a1da0b47143c8
X-Runtime: 0.154884
Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2013 10:52:47 GMT
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Server: nginx/1.2.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.19
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: Also saw "Content-Encoding: gzip" in chrome's inspector. Interesting how it didn't work for you in Safari. Have you fixed the issue? The page's content-type is 'text/html'. So gzip should be on by default.

Comment: This is the confusing part, yes content-encoding shows: gzip.  But Safari says, size=transferred (i.e. not compresse) and the tool on http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php says also: no compression.  I previously had Apache on that server and Safari as well as that tool on Gidnetwork both told me: compression is On.  So the question is, does Nginx deliver false-positives?

Comment: @Kumala I checked the request header in both chrome and Safari. The problem is that Safari doesn't send this header but chrome sends it: "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch". So nginx doesn't respond with a gzipped text because safari doesn't ask for it. Apache may just always gzip the content no matter what. I'd prefer the way nginx handling this

Comment: @Kumala on another thought, could you add this directive: "gzip_comp_level 5;" in your nginx config file. The default level of 1 is the least compression (fastest). I know 5 is a good value, suggested on a number of articles I read.

Comment: @Kumala Another note. My chrome shows the content of 6.1k, smaller than the unziped content of 22k. So it's indeed working in chrome.

Comment: You are right, looking at Chrome, it shows its compressed. I guess it has to do with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't specify the types to gzip. Add the following `gzip_types` line to your config file:

```
gzip on;
gzip_types text/css text/xml application/x-javascript application/atom+xml text/mathml text/plain text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor text/vnd.wap.wml text/x-component;
```

You might want to adjust the types to suit your configuration.

Note that `text/html` is on by default, so you do not have to specify it. If you use an http debugger, you will see that your current configuration (without the above `gzip_types` line) does indeed do gzip compression on the `php` file, but not on other types.

Comment: Doesn't work. I added the line, restartet the service, it still shows that there is no compression.

Comment: @Kumala - As I noted before, I see that the main php file is gzipped. However, no javscript files are compressed. You restarted the nginx service, correct?

Comment: I restarted the server, correct,  btw. the site is obviously not xxx.com, that is just a placeholder. I am using the Safari Web Inspector and it shows me that the size = transferred (hence not compressed) even though the content-type sows text/html

Comment: @Kumala - Are you sure nginx is running in front of your website? I ask that because in the html headers, your server shows as Apache/1.3.41. On my site, it shows nginx as the server.

Comment: @Kumala - your gzip is working for me there. I tried both Firefox and Internet Explorer.